# Iterate through all the elements containing a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to iterate through all the elements containing a specific class and pick a value from the array to randomly assign that specific class.

```
//start when the document is ready
$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict";
     $( "div" ).each(function( index, element ) {
         var colours = ["pink","yellow","aqua","teal","orange"];
         var picker = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
         $(".icon[id!='random']").addClass(colours[picker]);

     });
 });
```

With this code I can get it to perform the action to all the elements. I'm just stumped as to how I can get it to loop through each and generate a new random value and stop when it has reached the ened of all the items. These items are generated dynamically.

Comment: It looks like you are generating a new value each time, but you always add the class to the same set of elements. Try `$(this).find('.icon[id!=random]').addClass(...)`.

Comment: That appeared to work! Thank You!